# Prevent Email SPAM when my domain is used in other's email campaigns

Tags: email, subdomain, spam, spam-prevention

I am building a web app where a URL is created for a user to provide to their end user to link back to the app.  The link will be used in all kinds of communication including the potential my user's own mass email campaigns. My app will not be sending the email but rather my user's email address will be used. I know SPAM filters do trigger on keyword and link/url.  The question is:  How do I prevent my domain from triggering SPAM filters when I can not control the use of the domain?  Ultimately I don't want one bad email campaign to cause the entire user base's emails to start ending up in SPAM folders.

I know some will respond with: Do not give them a URL and instead control the communication routes. - my reply already is that I can not control the use of a URL and it's resending to others based on the purpose of the application.  The app is purpose built for flexibility of use with my user's existing communication channels.

- Also - I have googled and looked on stackoverflow all aspects of SPAM prevention and have not found documentation or informational help regarding the perspective of url's use rather than the domain itself send email.  Any guidance is very appreciative.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question.

Comment: Where can I post advise if I am not following the guidelines of this site?

Comment: Typical SO response from @MarcB , there. Useless.